# Palabra en español para "caching"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática, inglés

En el contexto de informática, `caching` puede ser utilizada para el proceso de guardar algo en una memoria rápida (caché del procesador, memoria RAM, etc).

¿Cual es la traducción correcta para esta palabra?

Answer (score 3):

Memoria caché es un concepto que la RAE reconoce:

> **[memoria caché](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OrlyaVd#FuFfcBb&o=h)**
>
> 1. f. Inform. memoria de acceso rápido de una computadora, que guarda temporalmente las últimas informaciones procesadas.

Por tanto, creo que **"guardar en memoria caché"** puede ser lo que buscas. Sin embargo, he oído con frecuencia el término inglés aun hablando en castellano.

Comment: Sería fácil que después de decir «la memoria caché» la gente empiece a usar la forma elíptica de «la caché», y de hecho, dicha forma ya está recogida: «**caché**. 1. *f. Inform.* **memoria caché**»

Answer (score 3):

En España por lo menos todas las variantes de *caché* y *cachear* se usan bastante:

- 'This app has a great caching system': 'Esta aplicación tiene un buen sistema de *cacheado*'.
- 'The solution is to cache the rendered information': 'La solución es *cachear* la información renderizada'.
- 'The cache holds recent data': 'La *caché* almacena información reciente'.
- 'The cache memory is almost full': 'La memoria *caché* está casi llena'.

Comment: Lo curioso es que con el uso de «cachear», dicho verbo ahora sea casi un autoantónimo porque «cachear» en español originalmente significa(ba) «ver si alguien tiene algo oculto» (~comprobar si algo está en la caché) en vez del acto de almanacer dichas cosas

Comment: @guifa Bueno, la raíz es la misma. La palabra inglesa *cache* viene del francés *caché*, que significa *oculto*. Pasó a significar un pequeño depósito oculto (por ejemplo, un altillo oculto en una casa donde guardas objetos de valor) y luego fue perdiendo el valor de oculto.

Answer (score 2):

En las comunidades informáticas en general se utilizan hispanizaciones de los términos técnicos en inglés.

Usa "**cacheado**", como en "*El cacheado de la memoria no es muy eficiente con esta herramienta*".

Answer (score 2):

En Android por ejemplo se usa la expresión **memoria intermedia**.

Comment: Sí, caching: manejo de cache, cachear, almacenamiento temporal, almacenamiento intermedio // kill buffer: cache de eliminación // cached data: datos en cache // trace cache: código de pista de caché // cache intermediate results: cachear resultados intermedios // precaching: caché previo // buffer: memoria intermedia para el almacenamiento de datos temporales en la comunicación // buffer: colchón de tiempo // stub program: programa intermediario // spooled: que almacena/almacenados temporalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente decimos **"Almacenamiento en caché"**. En Norteamerica incluso algunos pronuncian "cache" como ***kach*** y otros pronuncian ***keich***

Answer (score 1):

No, en español usamos *caching* y *cache* para referirnos a lo mismo: almacenamiento para ejecutar consultas recurrentes mas rapido.

```
Cache del Navegador.
Cache del website.
```