# Traducción de "caching mechanism"

Tags: traducción, informática

En http://excelramblings.blogspot.mx/2012/03/speeding-up-google-apps-script.html me encontré la frase

> it would be pretty straightforward to abstract getting spreadsheet
>   values using a caching mechanism

¿Cómo se traduce "caching mechanism"?

Dí con el artículo referido arriba durante mi investigación para la publicación de una pregunta en es.stackoverflow.com. Me gustaría evitar el uso de neologismos y tecnicismos en la redacción de mi pregunta para que esta sea útil incluso para usuarios de hojas de cálculo que no tienen antecedentes de formación como programadores profesionales, como es mi caso. ¿Es posible?

**Observaciones**
Esta pregunta es diferente a [Palabra en español para "caching"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15112/palabra-en-espa%C3%B1ol-para-caching) porque al contrario de aquella que el contexto es profesional de tecnologías de información, en este caso la intención es hacer la traducción para un público que no está famialiarizado con la jerga propia de los profesionales de las tecnologías de información.

Por otro lado, aquella pregunta aún no tiene una respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 3):

Pudieras traducirlo de las siguientes maneras:

- mecanismo de cacheo
- mecanismo de almacenamiento en caché
- mecanismo de memoria temporal
- mecanismo de almacenamiento que permita la agilización del proceso

Viendo que deseas emplear la traducción para usuarios que pudieran no estar muy relacionados con el área de las tecnologías de la información, te recomiendo que reemplaces la frase por algo que de la idea de que se obtendrá una agilización del proceso que se desea llevar a cabo, pues al final para eso es que se emplea la caché de los sistemas.

Answer (score 1):

Dado a que mencionas una traducción que no sea en un contexto profesional de tecnologías de información, una frase que viene a mi mente es la siguiente:

> Almacenamiento temporero

En tu ejemplo:

> Mecanismo de almacenamiento temporero